# Need help in finding the row of CSV which contains the values in array

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I have an array `LiveTick = ['ted3m index','US0003m index','USGG3m index']` and I am reading a CSV file `book1.csv`. I have to find the row which contains the values in csv.

For example, 15th row will contain `ted3m index 500 | 600` and 20th row will contain `US0003m index 800 | 900` and likewise.

I then have to get the values contained in the row and parse it for each value contained in array `LiveTick`. How do I proceed? Below is my sample code:

```
 with open('C:\\blp\\book1.csv', 'r') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
   writer = csv.writer(outf)
   for row in reader:
      for list in LiveTick:
         if list in row:
            print ('Found: {}'.format(row))
```

Comment: Does this csv have a header?

Comment: No. It has values only in 1st column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pandas, it's pretty fast and will do all reading, writing and filtering job for you out of the box:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\blp\\book1.csv')
filtered_df = df[df['your_column_name'].isin(LiveTick)]

# now you can save it
filtered_df.to_csv('C:\\blp\\book_filtered.csv')
```

Comment: This isn't necessarily more efficient than what OP is trying to achieve. For example, for very large dataframes it may not work since holding all data in memory is a requirement.

Comment: @Bendeberia I am getting empty dataframe as output.  I have to search whether items in LiveTick is present in the rows of CSV file. For example 15th row has ted3m index 500 | 600. I have to get this value for 'ted3m index' item in the list. I feel we are searching other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, but there are a few improvements you can make:

- Instead of a nested `for` loop which doesn't short-circuit, use `any` to compare the first column to multiple values.
- Write to your csv as you go along instead of just `print`. This is memory-efficient, as you hold in memory only one line at any one time.
- Define `outf` as an `open` object in your `with` statement.
- Do not shadow built-in `list`. Use another identifier, e.g. `i`, for elements in `LiveTick`.

Here's a demo:

```
with open('in.csv', 'r') as f, open('out.csv', 'wb', newline='') as outf:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    writer = csv.writer(outf, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if any(i in row[0] for i in LiveTick):
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Its not working properly. I have to search whether items in LiveTick is present in the rows of CSV file. For example 15th row has ted3m index 500 | 600. I have to get this value for 'ted3m index' item in the list

Comment: `Its not working properly`. Sorry, that's not enough for me to work with. Try and debug and find which line isn't work for you and I can try & help.

Comment: I am getting empty output in 'out.csv'. I feel we are searching other way around. Find whether row value is present in LiveTick list.